# Service Reference object not Serializing

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

A fairly complex object `RequestList` defined in a WCF Service Reference is also an input parameter for a method in the same Service Reference. An XML is already generated client-side, so all we need to do is XmlSerialize the object, then deserialize the client-side xml. An exception is being thrown when trying to create a new `XmlSerializer` with the given type.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestList));
```

throws an InvalidOperationException:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert  type 'ServiceReference.Parameter[]' 
  to 'ServiceReference.Parameter'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference.Parameter' 
  to'ServiceReference.Paramter[]'
```

Shouldn't arrays be easily serializable? Why is this error being thrown and how can I fix it?

Comment: can u pls paste definition of RequestList, especially Parameter[] field/property.

Comment: Have you checked your object to contain any circular reference as that might be one of the reason for it to fail. Also try the code XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(); ser.Serialize(obj,stream); and if you want the xml string read it from the stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. Apparently there is a bug of some sort. In the definition of the `RequestList` class, there was a parameter with a double array `Parameter[][]`. Apparently that causes issues. The fix is to make it a single array: `Parameter[]`. Once I did this, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is not directly related to a bug or something. You are probably using an object, or that object has a property which can not be serialized using xml serialization. 
For instance, `Dictionary<T>` can not be serialized directly; it gives error; in order to use `Dictionary<T>` in xml serialization, one should implement IXmlSerializable interface by inheriting dictionary.

This may not be the case, since I do not know what you are trying to serialize on the otherhand.

Comment: No dictionary. Just a very large structure of ints, bools, doubles, decimal and DateTime types. DateTime types are serializable, right?